# Apply css styles within the parent page to an iframe of the same domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, iframe

I'm trying to apply a stylesheet to the contents of an iframe from the parent - yes, I know there's been several questions asked in the past regarding this same idea, but I'm working within the same domain here and I've tried nearly every solution on this website and none of them have worked. Here's what I got:

```
<html>
<title>Untitled</title>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" media="screen">

    var cssLink = document.createElement("link") 
    cssLink.href = "http://domain.extension/style.css"; 
    cssLink .rel = "stylesheet"; 
    cssLink .type = "text/css"; 
    frames['#window'].document.body.appendChild(cssLink);

</script>

<style type="text/css" media="screen">

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}

iframe#window {
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe name="window" id="window" sandbox="allow-forms allow-scripts" src="http://domain.extension/example"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you just include the stylesheet in the iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On both scripts (the one in the frame and the one in main window) you need to set document.domain to your domain. This needs to be before your $(document).ready() and such..

```
document.domain = "ra.gs";
var cssLink = $("<link/>",{
    href: "http://static.ra.gs/ttnnmnd/HFnmays5q/style.css",
    rel: "stylesheet",
    type: "text/css"
});

var iframeBody = $(window.document.frames["window"].window.document).contents().find("body");

iframeBody.prepend(cssLink);
```

Comment: I can't modify the contents within the iframe at all.

Comment: @luke The domain is the same though, right?I've updated my answer. I did things a bit differently using more jquery than you originally used. You might also consider just loading that url into your page but instead of using an iframe, into a div.  $("#loadIntoMe").load('http : //hello.com/whatever');

Comment: @teewuane, I have been talking to luke in chat, he has said that the `<iframe>` source is on a main domain - tumblr.com and his parent page is on a subdomain - subdomain.tumblr.com.

Comment: Yeah unless there's a way to cope with the subdomain, I'm stumped.

Comment: What is the value of $(window.document.frames["window"].window.document).domain ?  If I am understanding correctly, its 'tumblr.com', and the value of document.domain (your main window) is subdomain.tumblr.com, yeah? So what if you set in your main window, document.domain = 'tumblr.com';, do that before any other code. They will then match, right? Code executed from within the iframe will recognize it's document.domain as tumblr.com by default since that is what it is. Does that work?

Answer (score 1):

From what I know this is not possible due to sandboxing. Why not use AJAX? (Since this is on the same domain.)

To implement this, you could create a `<div id="frame"></div>` element and use the `.load` function to load the page into the div like this:

```
$('#frame').load('/somepage.html');
```

Comment: I'm not sure how I would go about it using AJAX - example?

Comment: Or, if you are using jQuery, which you are ... I will update the answer for you.

Comment: Why bother linking to a basic tutorial on AJAX? This isn't an answer.

Comment: @MentalFrog, Sorry, I have realized that, I am currently updating the answer for him.

Comment: So rather than using an iframe, I'm creating a window to the same page as the iframe using a div? Or am I supposed to load the css using jquery?

Comment: Since you are using AJAX, your original CSS on the parent page **can** interact with the page that you have loaded. (So you don't have to load the CSS using jQuery).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm fairly new to this so I'm not quite understanding how I would set this up. Can you make an example - it doesn't have to work I just need to see how you went about putting it together. I need the styles applied to the parent to not affect the iframe if that changes anything.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand your last sentence. Do you want to style the contents of the frame? (e.g. load the page contents into the `<div>` and apply the same style from the parent page to the contents within it?)

Comment: I want to apply a stylesheet that's linked in the head of the parent page to the contents of the iframe ( or the page loaded into the div ). If you look at my markup in the original question, all I'm trying to do is apply the css to the contents of the iframe, while still being about to style the parent using the style tags.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17197/discussion-between-luke-and-qiang)